# I'm trying to make the OMDB API call using the text in the input field and pressing the search button

Tags: reactjs

My code is here: https://github.com/justgoof9/IMDB/blob/master/src/App.js
This is the error i receive: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCnTJ.png

Can anyone show me the way to make the API call after the user has inputted a movie name and pressed the search button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close -- you just need to update the API url that you're calling. Specifically, you had not set a movie id in your state, so your api call looked like this: http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=&apikey=480344f1. If you follow that url in a browser, you'll see that it returns the error message you were logging. If you specify a movie id (e.g. tt3896198), you'll see you get a proper API response http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=480344f1.

I updated the snippet below to set an initial movie id in your component's state:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Input } from "antd";
import "./App.css";
import { Button } from "antd";

const API_KEY = "480344f1";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      movie:"tt3896198",
      movies: []
    };
    this.APIURL = `http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=${
      this.state.movie
    }&apikey=${API_KEY}`;
  }

  changeUserInput = movie => {
    this.setState({ movie });
  };

  onSubmit= (movie) => {
   this.componentWillMount();
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch(this.APIURL)
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
        const updatedMovies = this.state.movies;
        updatedMovies.push(data);
        this.setState({
          movies:updatedMovies,
        })
        console.log(this.state.movies);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
        <br />
        <br />

        <Input placeholder="Basic usage" placeholder="Search Movies" onChange={e => this.changeUserInput(e.target.value)} />
        <Button
        type="primary"
        shape="circle"
        icon="search"
        onClick={() => this.onSubmit()} />
      </div>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The way I solved it was , I moved the this.APIURL into the componentWillMount. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Nischal sounds good, I'm glad it all worked out. Have fun making the app!